# How to get list of groups followed by my page in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get list of all the groups my Facebook page is following. I've searched the graph API, but could not find any info in this regard.

I could not find any relevant API

I am trying use this with C#, I am not looking for any sample code, but if someone can point me in the direction?

Thanks!

Comment: in general, if there is no api for it, it´s not possible. i checked out the api reference for pages, and there is no endpoint for groups.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v4.0/group, I am not exploring this to see if I can post a URL to a group that my page is subscribed to and next step is to how to post as page?